# Replacing url scheme of ios app at runtime?

Tags: ios

Can I replace my ios url scheme at run time.or can we replace Info.plist file programmatically?

Comment: You can't modify your bundle contents while running, you don't have write access to that directory.

Answer (score 9):

I saw an answer to this question here: [link](http://img.pandawhale.com/39215-grumpy-cat-no-Vyfj.jpeg)